# Como puedo hacer busquedas parciales en mongodb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Cuando busco "leche gloria", en los resultados me muestra:

```
    {
        "_id": "Leche GLORIA Niños",
        "name": "Leche GLORIA Niños"
    },
    {
        "_id": "Leche evaporada GLORIA light",
        "name": "Leche evaporada GLORIA light"
    },
    {
        "_id": "Yogurt GLORIA sauco",
        "name": "Yogurt GLORIA sauco"
    },
    {
        "_id": "Queso crema GLORIA",
        "name": "Queso crema GLORIA"
    },
```

Pienso que los dos primeros objetos si están bien, pero no debería salir los otros dos. Aquí mi código.

```
Product.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                $and: [{name2: /leche/i , name2: /gloria/i}],
                active: true,
            },
        },
        { $group: { _id: '$name', name: { $first: '$name' } } },
        { $limit: 20 },
    ]).then((products) => {
        res.status(200).send({ products });
    });
```

Se supone que por la condicional AND, no debería mostrarme los objetos que no tienen la palabra "leche".
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal o que me falta? Ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 1):

El error está en

```
$and: [{name2: /leche/i , name2: /gloria/i}]
```

que deberían ser 2 objetos diferentes

```
$and: [{name2: /leche/i} , {name2: /gloria/i}]
```

Aunque me parece más sencillo hacer todo con un único regex:

1. `leche` siempre antes de `gloria`

   ```
   name2: /leche.*gloria/i
   ```
2. `leche` y `gloria` en cualquier posición

   ```
   name2: /^(?=.*leche)(?=.*gloria)/i
   ```

... a elección del consumidor ;-)

Comment: Ah que tonto que soy, me funcionó y gracias por las otras sugerencias. ¿Crees que me puedas pasar algún link donde pueda aprender más sobre esto?. Soy nuevo en mongoDB y me interesa mucho aprender a hacer búsquedas más complejas. Gracias.

Comment: @RenzoAndreCondoMiranda la verdad ni idea, de hecho no sé mucho de mongo, sólo lo uso eventualmente. Mi respuesta vino de la lógica de JavaScript (si un objeto tiene la misma clave definida 2 veces, se sobreescribe, por eso vi que pasabas 1 sola)... y la parte de expresiones regulares también viene de usarlas fuera de mongo